# How to get Name of a JSON field based on the Value in JavaScript?

Tags: javascript, json

I have the following JSON File:

```
   "fields": {
        "x1": {
            "name": "AnExteremLongName"
        },
        "x2": {
            "name": "AnotherExteremLongName"
        },
    },"row": [
        {
            "x1": {
                "name":"Some random Text"
            },
            "x2": {
                "name":"Other random Text"
            }
        }, ....
```

This is basically a table and to reduce the size of the Json file, the names are extraced into this x values.

I want to get the the Value of "AnExteremLongName" so I have to first get the representive X value. How can I do this without reading all varibles and store them into a "Hashmap"

So basically something like:

```
String getParamNamebyValue(String ParamValue);
```

Comment: I suppose you'll have to iterate, as this is backwards from how it's designed to work. Imagine you just have a phonebook and a certain number, and you need to look up the name associated with that number. It's kinda like that.

Comment: @Stefan: what would you exactly expect as the return value of getParamNamebyValue("AnExteremLongName")? "fields.x1"? And what if "AnExteremLongName" appears multiple times in the json string?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You'll have to iterate through the object properties using `for in` and compare them. But it is not really fast and I would not recommend it.

Something like [this](http://jsfiddle.net/2fgBT/2/).

Comment: yes, I think so too... would it be better to send the list without this optimization, even if the paramternames could take >10 characters?

Comment: I'd suggest you don't optimize this in your code but rather just compress the Json you send out. If those things repeat themselves a lot the compression will bring the size down..

Comment: +1 for compression. JSON has a quite light footprint so if it's still too large you'll have to work on your data and make use of hashing, pagination to optimize your application.